# Platform independent /dev/null in c++

Tags: c++, stream, ostream, default-parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing a no-op std::ostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760301/implementing-a-no-op-stdostream)

Is there any stream equivalent of NULL in c++? I want to write a function that takes in a stream if the user wants to have the internal outputted to somewhere, but if not, the output goes into some fake place

```
void data(std::stream & stream = fake_stream){
    stream << "DATA" ;
}
```

i want to be able to chose to do `data()` or `data(std::cout)`

Comment: You're looking for some kind of "black hole" stream that you can write too but which does nothing with the data?  You could derive one I suppose, but most people would just check that the stream pointer isn't NULL before attempting to write to it.

Comment: What does `"but destroyed if not"` mean? Why don't you write pseudocode to clarify your question?

Comment: as in: i dont care where it goes, as long as it doenst show up any where a user would check, like a file, or the terminal

Comment: So basically the ostream equivalent of /dev/null

Comment: why the negative vote and close votes??

Comment: @calc: My guess, didn't downvote: because the question isn't really clear. As @Nawaz says, what does "but destroyed if not" mean?

Comment: @calc: See my answer again, edited it.

Comment: This question is closed as exact duplicate but no link is given to what it is a duplicate of. Can we get a link to the other question?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Edit**: Taken from @Johannes Schaub - litb's mail [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/msg/6125e4267ce31d7a) with slight modifications:

```
template<typename Ch, typename Traits = std::char_traits<Ch> >
struct basic_nullbuf : std::basic_streambuf<Ch, Traits> {
     typedef std::basic_streambuf<Ch, Traits> base_type;
     typedef typename base_type::int_type int_type;
     typedef typename base_type::traits_type traits_type;

     virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) {
         return traits_type::not_eof(c);
     }
};

// convenient typedefs
typedef basic_nullbuf<char> nullbuf;
typedef basic_nullbuf<wchar_t> wnullbuf;

// buffers and streams
// in some .h
extern std::ostream cnull;
extern std::wostream wcnull;

// in a concrete .cpp
nullbuf null_obj;
wnullbuf wnull_obj;
std::ostream cnull(&null_obj);
std::wostream wcnull(&wnull_obj);
```

Use those:

```
void data(std::ostream& stream = cnull){
  // whatever...
}
```

---

Now, this looks cool and all, but the following is way shorter and works, because if a null pointer is provided to the constructor of `ostream`, it automatically sets the badbit and silently ignores any writes:

```
// in .h
extern std::ostream cnull;
extern std::wostream wcnull;

// in .cpp
std::ostream cnull(0);
std::wostream wcnull(0);
```

The standard guarantees this works, beginning from `27.6.2.2 [lib.ostream.cons] p1` which describes the constructor of `ostream` that takes a pointer to a `streambuf`:

> Effects: Constructs an object of class `basic_ostream`, assigning initial values to the base class by calling `basic_ios<charT,traits>::init(sb)`.

The relevant function from `basic_ios`, `27.4.4.1 [lib.basic.ios.cons] p3`:

> `void init(basic_streambuf<charT,traits>* sb);`
>   Postconditions: The postconditions of this function are indicated in Table 89:

The important row from Table 89:

> rdstate() -- goodbit if sb is not a null pointer, otherwise badbit.

What happens if the `badbit` is set is described under `27.6.2.6 [lib.ostream.unformatted]`:

> Each unformatted output function begins execution by constructing an object of class `sentry`. If this object returns true, while converting to a value of type bool, the function endeavors to generate the requested output.

This implies that, in case the `sentry` is false, it does not. Here is how the `sentry` converts to `bool`, taken from `27.6.2.3 [lib.ostream::sentry] p3 & p5`:

> 3) If, after any preparation is completed, `os.good()` is `true`, `ok_ == true` otherwise, `ok_ == false`.
>
> 5) `operator bool();`
>   Effects: Returns ok_.

(`ok_` is a member of `ostream::sentry` of type `bool`.)

---

Note that these quotes are still present in C++11, just in different places. In order of appearance in this answer:

- `27.6.2.2 [lib.ostream.cons] p1` => `27.7.3.2 [ostream.cons] p1`
- `27.4.4.1 [lib.basic.ios.cons] p3` => `27.5.5.2 [basic.ios.cons]`
- Table 89 => Table 128
- `27.6.2.6 [lib.ostream.unformatted]` => `27.7.3.7 [ostream.unformatted] p1`
- `27.6.2.3 [lib.ostream::sentry] p3 & p5` => `27.7.3.4 [ostream::sentry] p4 & p5`

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer.  Is there a difference in `os.good()` for the two schemes?  With `std::ostream os(nullptr)`, `assert(os)` will fail whereas with `std::ostream os(&nullobj)`, `assert(os)` will not?  I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Linux file /dev/null is a black hole like you're looking for.  In Windows there's a device called NUL:.  I've never tried to open that file, but I've used it from the command line

Comment: ... you could do the same thing without opening these special files. Technically all you need to do is accept arguments in your `<<` overload, and then simply not do anything with them.

Comment: thats true. but the user would still have to create the stream in the first place

Comment: and how would i use it? `std::ostream stream = NUL` and `std::ostream stream = std::ostream(NUL)` dont work as parameters

Comment: @calc: If you want a non-portable one, you can try `std::ostream stream("/dev/null")` on Linux / Unix.

Comment: No no, the whole point is that you make your OWN ostream (called blackhole or something), which when written to simply ignores all data. This has nothing to do with a null pointer.

Answer (score -1):

you can try ostream(NULL,false), the first input is target output and I don't know what the second input exaclty mean but after tracing code it seems just because ostream has no place to write to, calling `operator <<` is just ignored by ostream. I mean in the first call state changes to bad and after that it's always ignoring input data because of stream state ,so you can use the following code :

```
void data(std::ostream & stream = ostream(NULL,false)){
    stream << "DATA" ;
}
```

Comment: -1, this won't work. A temporary may only bind to a `const T&` reference, but a constant stream cannot be written to. I think MSVC allows this as an extension, but ...

Comment: it works and compiles using vc++ but seems to have some problems with gcc.