# How do I redirect stderr to /dev/null in C++?

Tags: c++, linux

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main() {
   
    //read the lines from the piped file using cin
    string response;
    int i = 0;
    while (getline(cin, response)) {
        //if the response is empty, stop
        if (response.empty()) {
            break;
        }
        
        //Write each odd line (1,3, etc..) to stderr (cerr) 
        //Write each even line (2,4. etc..) to stdout (cout) 
        if (i % 2 != 1) { //send odd to stderr
            cerr << "err: " << response << endl;
        }
        else { //send even to stdout
            cout << "out: " << response << endl;
        }
        i++;

    }

        
    return 0;
}
```

I want to redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`, how would I go about doing so? I'm new to C++ and trying to learn by practicing, however, I'm not easily able to find an answer that fits my existing program.

Comment: Do you need to redirect it from within the program? Typically you just use it, and the caller can run with  `2>/dev/null` to discard it if they want to.

Comment: Yes, I would like to do it from within the program, not from the command line. I understand how to do it from the command line already.

Comment: In that case, check `man dup2`, and use it to replace file descriptor 2 (the fd for stderr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the excellent commentary above, it is pretty easy to make a “null” streambuf sink in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

struct null_streambuf: public std::streambuf
{
  using int_type = std::streambuf::int_type;
  using traits   = std::streambuf::traits_type;

  virtual int_type overflow( int_type value ) override
  {
    return value;
  }
};
```

To use it, just set the `rdbuf`:

```
int main()
{
  std::cerr.rdbuf( new null_streambuf );
  std::cerr << "Does not print!\n";
}
```

If you wish to be able to turn it off and on, you will have to remember the original and restore it, not forgetting to `delete` the new null_streambuf.

```
int main()
{
  std::cerr << "Prints!\n";

  auto original_cerr_streambuf = std::cerr.rdbuf( new null_streambuf );
  std::cerr << "Does not print.\n";

  delete std::cerr.rdbuf( original_cerr_streambuf );
  std::cerr << "Prints again!\n";
}
```

This does have the objective effect of being compiled to code, which I suspect is the advantage you are looking for: the ability to dynamically enable and disable diagnostic output.

This is, however, the usual function of a debug build, where you use the `DEBUG` macro to decide whether or not to compile something (such as error output operations) into the final executable.

Keep in mind that this does *not* disable output on standard error via other means, but only through `cerr`.

Comment: Is it possible to do without the struct ? Just curious, otherwise, I think this is a very well thought out answer and seems to fit my needs. Thank you for the input!

Comment: I think just `std::cerr.rdbuf(nullptr);` is permitted and will have mostly the same effect.

Comment: [Yes, but doing so sets badbit, and efforts to endrun around this may invoke UB.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25690636/is-it-valid-to-construct-an-stdostream-from-a-null-buffer). Whether that is an actual issue or not IDK, but I prefer not to poke the bear.

Comment: @Dúthomhas that link says `badbit` is set if `ostream` is *constructed* with a `nullptr`, but it doesn't say anything about what happens if `nullptr` is passed to `rdbuf()` after construction. Neither does [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf), but it does say that an `ostream` can have "no associated stream buffer", so there has to be a valid way for `nullptr` to be used, without putting the stream into an error state.

Comment: @aschepler - Thanks, that's even easier, plain and simple. You should submit an answer and I'll accept it as a solution. :)