# How to drop the expressions after <<?

Tags: c++, cout

There is a very simple log "system":

```
#include <iostream>

#if true
#  define LOG std::cout
#else
#  define LOG
#endif

int main()
{
  LOG << "hi" << std::endl;
   
}
```

My goal is to make it *conditional* i.e. to **not** do anything when the condition is false.

What I've tried:

- #undef LOG: not good, "error: 'LOG' was not declared in this scope"
- #define LOG {}: not good, "error: expected primary-expression before '<<' token"

If I need to keep the `<<` functionality, how can I drop all inputs towards `LOG`?

Comment: This isn't C.  Looks like C++.

Comment: Write your own ostream which just ignores everything.

Comment: Don't use `#define` for this. Make `LOG` a real object that has behavior at runtime.

Comment: Actually, I found one. [See if this question helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240950/platform-independent-dev-null-in-c).

Comment: I just want to *not* build the log messages into the binary when not needed. So now I can do `#if preprocess_condition \ LOG << "something debug"; \ #endif` everywhere which is too much typing. Hence I thought to solve this purely with preprocessor macros.

Comment: Another option is to define `LOG` to be a function-style macro that takes in an input parameter for the output data, and then you can simply ignore that parameter if needed: `#if condition==true #define LOG(values) std::cout << values << std::endl; #else #define LOG(values) #endif` And then you can use it like this: `LOG("hi")`, `LOG("value = " << variable)`, etc

Comment: If you *must* use the `<<` syntax, consider `boost::iostreams`: to create a stream that goes nowhere: https://godbolt.org/z/M6sxKan9K

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option would be to use an object that just swallows all the `operator<<` calls (like @tkausl suggested in the comments):

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Waz58eP98)

```cpp
#if SOMETHING
#define LOG std::cout
#else
struct nullout_t {};
template<class T>
constexpr nullout_t const& operator<<(nullout_t const& no, T&&) { return no; }
constexpr nullout_t nullout;
#define LOG nullout
#endif // SOMETHING

int main()
{
    LOG << "hello world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Please note however this method completely relies on the compiler being able to eliminate the entire log statement.

So if your logging has any observable side-effects (or the compiler simply isn't able to prove it's dead code), you still will end up with some of the logging code running.

e.g. a simple string concatenation is already enough to prevent gcc from optimizing it out completely:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/Waz58eP98)

```cpp
int main()
{
    LOG << std::string("hello") + std::string("world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

I wouldn't recommend using `boost:iostreams` with `null_sink` like @AndyG suggested, because that makes it very hard (if not impossible) for compilers to completely optimize out. (In the [linked example](https://godbolt.org/z/M6sxKan9K) you can see that `main()` still actually calls `operator<<` on the iostream) This is due to iostreams performing formatting first before actually passing the final result to the sink (`null_sink`) - and formatting depends on the stream manipulators applied to the stream and the locale imbued into it - so the compiler would need to prove that nothing of that has any side effect for it to be able to optimize it out completely (which is rather hard).

---

If you want to be able to completely get rid of the entire logging code, you'd have to change your `LOG` macro so that the preprocessor can completely remove the `operator<<` calls as well, e.g.:

[godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/esrjfjeer)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#if SOMETHING
#define LOG(...) std::cout __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define LOG(...)
#endif // SOMETHING

int main()
{
    LOG(<< "hello world!\n");
    LOG(<< "there are " << 5 << " cookies in the " << std::string("jar") << std::endl);
    return 0;
}
```

By using the preprocessor to remove the code you can get rid of all logging logic, even if it would have observable side effects.