# Is it possible to disable google test assertions with some macro?

Tags: c++, macros, googletest

Consider I have hot function with a loop and there is gtest assertion in it:

```
for (i = 0; i < BIG_NUMBER; i++)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(a[i] > 0.) << "a[i] = " << a[i];
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

I want to have 2 different build types for the program:

1. With all assertions enabled (debug type)
2. With all assertions disabled (release type)

Is it possible?

Maybe is it possible to re-define the macro `EXPECT_TRUE`?

Comment: Do you mean having that assert enabled when you compile in debug mode and disabled in release mode? What's wrong with #ifdefs? You could of course change gtest's sources but #ifdefs would be a cleaner way to do it

Comment: I haven't used google test assertions but looking at the code you have, you have to not only disable the tests but you'll also have to define it to something which supports the overloaded `<<` operator.

Comment: @Marco A., yes of course, I meant to use `#ifdef`s to re-define the macro.

Comment: @R Sahu, yes, maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760301/implementing-a-no-op-stdostream

Comment: But I wonder whether there is some commonly-used techique for that. Becase it look strange that disabling debug output needs some additional implementation.

Comment: @IlyaPalachev `EXPECT_TRUE` is _not_ debug output.  It is a unit test.  To disable asserts, just compile with `NDEBUG` defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I can't imagine wanting to do this, except locally, to
make the tests run faster to get to some more exotic cases;
`EXPECT_TRUE` et al. are only useful in the Google test
environment, and should only appear in unit tests, not in the
body of your code.

Locally, I'd use a separate macro (so that someone reading the
code knows immediatly that it is a conditional test), say
`COND_EXPECT_TRUE` (for conditional EXPECT_TRUE), defined
something like:

```
#ifdef ALL_TESTS
#define COND_EXPECT_TRUE EXPECT_TRUE
#else
#define COND_EXPECT_TRUE dummyOutput
#endif
```

, where `dummyOutput` is an unopened `std::ofstream` somewhere.
(Or if you really want to be sure, you can define a `nullstream`
class, which outputs into thin air.  But in this case, and
conversions in the output will still occur; in an unopened
`std::ofstream`, the fact that it is in an error state inhibits
the conversions.)

Comment: That is what I wanted to hear. Gtest macros should not be used inside the code of application.