# ostream usage in C++

Tags: c++, debugging, g++, ostream

I have a program showing error. How to resolve the error and to use ostream to display output
I use g++ compiler in my ubuntu

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ostream out;
    out<<"Hello World";
}
```

Comment: What is the error? (Aside from the fact that you probably should have used `std::cout`)

Comment: Have a look on this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524524/creating-an-ostream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ostream that you want (attached to the display) has already been defined as `cout`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
}
```

Not all `ostream`s send the stream to the terminal display.

Answer (score 2):

`std::ostream` does not have a default constructor, this:

```
ostream out;
```

will be a compile time error.

You are probably wanting to use `std::cout` (as has already been stated).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, include  `#include <fstream>` .  Secondly, change `ofstream out` to `ofstream out("file.txt")` .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

  ofstream out ("c:\\test5.txt");
  out<<"Hello World";
  out.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do some output you need to get the right `ostream`. As Drew Dormann showed you, you can use `std::cout` for writing on standard output. You can also use `std::cerr` for the standard error, and finally you can instantiate your own `fstream` if you want, for instance, to write on a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream outfile ("output.txt", fstream::out);

    outfile << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    // Always close streams
    outfile.close();
}
```

As side note: i suggest not to export the `std` namespace (`use namespace std`) in your programs ([see this faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.5))