# Apply a facet to all stream output, use custom string manipulators

Tags: c++, locale, facet

I would like to create a custom facet that applies to all streamed text output, and access the operated-on stream's internal extensible array (i.e. via iword).

If I were only interested in having the custom string manipulator operate on numbers, I could do something like what's described here:
[C++ custom stream manipulator that changes next item on stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799599/c-custom-stream-manipulator-that-changes-next-item-on-stream/799877#799877)

If I didn't need access to the iosbase, I could use codecvt's do_out method, as is described here:
[How to easily indent output to ofstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391746/how-to-easily-indent-output-to-ofstream), but I don't have access to the stream's ios_base within the codecvt facet (as far as I can tell).

Is there a way to define a custom facet that will be called on all stream output, as is the case with codecvt, but where I have access to ios_base& as is the case with num_put?  Is there a way I can access the stream the codecvt facet is currently being applied to?

Comment: This smells like XY problem. What are you actually trying achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution to this question, but I am not sure what the policy/guidelines are on quoting external links/references in stackExchange.

I created a custom streambuf object ([creating an ostream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524524/creating-an-ostream)) that contained a secondary store for the characters that were processed by stream.

I have looked at your github source -- and was wondering if, when you create your indent_facet, if you could pass the stream to the indent_facet constructor; and then use that pointer to get the streambuf; and through that, the secondary store?

Like I said, I have a much more detailed description of what I'm thinking about.

Thanks,

Tom